# How to apply rxjs operators to a single formcontrol in a formgroup

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms

```
filterForm = this.fb.group({
    filterType: [''],
    filterValue:['']
    searchText:['']
  });
this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res); //some backend call
});
```

I want to apply few rxjs operators like debounce, distinctUntilChanged only to searchText form controller so that I can make api call using the whole form value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a get for **select** the control and a **pipe** before the subscribe:

```
filterForm = this.fb.group({
    filterType: [''],
    filterValue:['']
    searchText:['']
  });
this.filterForm.get('searchText').valueChanges.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounce(500),
)
.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res); //some backend call
});
```

Comment: this.filterForm.get('searchText').valueChanges will give value of searchText formcontrol, not the complete form value.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is piping only the one field where you want to apply the operators and then replace its value with the current form value:

```
this.filterForm.get('searchText').valueChanges.pipe(
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounce(N),
    map(() => this.filterForm.value),
  )
  .subscribe(res => {
    ...
  });
```

Comment: This wont help me as I wont able to listen to formcontrols like filterType and filterValue. I have to write again like 

this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
});

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to debounce only `searchText` but at the same time react to changes in any input fields? This contradicts each other.

Comment: **YES, As I need all the values to make the http call.**

I can split into 2 parts like below but i need a optimal solution.
`
this.filterForm.get('searchText').valueChanges.pipe(
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounce(N),
    map(() => this.filterForm.value),
  )
  .subscribe(res => {
    ...
  });

------------------------

merge(
      this.filterForm.controls['filterType'].valueChanges,
      this.filterForm.controls['filterValue'].valueChanges
    )
      .pipe(map(() => this.filterForm.value))
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
`